# How to print one log line per every 10 epochs when training models with tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, callback

When I fit the model with:

`model.fit(X, y, epochs=40, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)` it prints one log line for each epoch as:

```py
Epoch 1/100
0s - loss: 0.2506 - acc: 0.5750 - val_loss: 0.2501 - val_acc: 0.3750
Epoch 2/100
0s - loss: 0.2487 - acc: 0.6250 - val_loss: 0.2498 - val_acc: 0.6250
Epoch 3/100
0s - loss: 0.2495 - acc: 0.5750 - val_loss: 0.2496 - val_acc: 0.6250
.....
```

How can I print the log line per very 10 epochs as follows?

```py
Epoch 10/100
0s - loss: 0.2506 - acc: 0.5750 - val_loss: 0.2501 - val_acc: 0.3750
Epoch 20/100
0s - loss: 0.2487 - acc: 0.6250 - val_loss: 0.2498 - val_acc: 0.6250
Epoch 30/100
0s - loss: 0.2495 - acc: 0.5750 - val_loss: 0.2496 - val_acc: 0.6250
.....
```

Comment: this is easy to implement if you are ok with just printing this sintetized log on a text flie instead that on screen, are you ok with that?

Comment: Yeah that's fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This callback will create and write on a log text file what you want:

```py
log_path = "text_file_name.txt"  # it will be created automatically


class print_training_on_text_every_10_epochs_Callback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, logpath):
        self.logpath = logpath

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        with open(self.logpath, "a") as writefile:  # put log_path here
            with redirect_stdout(writefile):
                if (int(epoch) % 10) == 0:
                    print(
                        f"Epoch: {epoch:>3}"
                        + f" | Loss: {logs['loss']:.4e}"
                        + f" | Accuracy: {logs['accuracy']:.4e}"
                        + f" | Validation loss: {logs['val_loss']:.4e}"
                        + f" | Validation accuracy: {logs['val_accuracy']:.4e}"
                    )
                    writefile.write("\n")


my_callbacks = [
    print_training_on_text_every_10_epochs_Callback(logpath=log_path),
]
```

You want to call it like this.

```py
model.fit(
    training_dataset,
    epochs=60,
    verbose=0, # Must be zero, else it would still print log per epoch.
    validation_data=validation_dataset, 
    callbacks=my_callbacks,
)
```

The text file will be updated only after 10 epochs have passed

This is what i get on the text file

```
Epoch:   0 | Loss: 5.3454e+00 | Valid loss: 4.2420e-01

Epoch:  10 | Loss: 3.1342e-02 | Valid loss: 3.4554e-02

Epoch:  20 | Loss: 1.6330e-02 | Valid loss: 2.2512e-02
```

The first epoch is numbered 0, the second 1 and so on.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. There is lot of white space in between the two lines (like 10 lines). I s there a way to reduce it?

Comment: It was an indentation error from copy pasting the code in the line ```writefile.write("\n")```